# Binding the 2 EVALS on one LinkButton

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am looking a way to allow my two EVALS in my CS. The 1st string works perfectly, but the other one does not

This is my aspx

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvMaterialsList" runat="server" ondatabound="lvMaterialsList_DataBound" 
                    onpagepropertieschanging="lvMaterialsList_PagePropertiesChanging" OnItemCommand="lvMaterialsList_ItemCommand">


                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>      
                         <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("SupplierProduct")%> ' Visible="false"  /></td>
                                        <td>                         
                            <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="ltRefNo" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("ReqMatID") %>' Visible="false"  />
                             <%# Eval("SupplierProduct")%> 
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SupplierProductID") %>' width="1px" Visible="false" />
                                        </td>
                            <td><%# Eval("Quantity") %></td>
                            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtAlloted" runat="server" type="number" Text=''
                                                class="form-control" width="60px" min='1'/></td>
                            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" OnClientClick='return confirm("Withdraw materials?")' CommandName="updateused">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>&nbsp;</asp:LinkButton>                                               
                            </td>
                            <td><asp:Literal ID="ltUsed" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Used") %>'
                                                Visible="false" />
                                                 <%# Eval("Used")%>
                                                 </td>
                            <td><%# Eval("Status") %></td>
                            <td><%# Eval("DateAdded", "{0: MMMM dd, yyyy}") %></td>
                            <td><%# Eval("DateModified", "{0: MMMM dd, yyyy}") %></td>
                            <td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:LinkButton Text="Additional" class="btn btn-primary " ID="lbtnUpdate" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ProjectID")+","+ Eval("ReqMatID")%>'
                                    PostBackUrl='<%# string.Format(" AdditionalAlloc.aspx?ID={0}&MID={1}", Eval("ProjectID"), Eval("ReqMatID"))%>'></asp:LinkButton>
                                     <asp:LinkButton Text="Add req" class="btn btn-primary " ID="lblAdd" runat="server" 
                                    PostBackUrl='<%# string.Format(" AddReq.aspx?ID={0}", Eval("ProjectID"))%>'></asp:LinkButton>

                               <a href='EditMaterial.aspx?ID=<%# Eval("ReqMatID") %>'><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>&nbsp;
                              <%-- <a href='../Reports/SupplierDetails.aspx?ID=<%# Eval("SupplierID") %>'><i class="fa fa-print"></i></a>&nbsp;--%>
                               <a href='DeleteMaterial.aspx?ID=<%# Eval("ReqMatID") %>'" onclick='return confirm("Delete record?")'>
                                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                                </a>
                            </td>     
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>

                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="12"><h2 class="text-center">No records found.</h2></td>


                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </EmptyDataTemplate>
               </asp:ListView>
```

This is the code that I use.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Admin_Project_AdditionalAlloc : System.Web.UI.Page
{
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Helper.GetCon());
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (Request.QueryString["ID"] != null)
    {
        int userID = 0;
        bool validUser = int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString(), out userID);
        int productID = 0;
        bool product = int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["MID"].ToString(), out productID);
        if (validUser)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GetInfo(userID);
                GetMaterialsInfo(productID);
                GetProjects();
                GetMaterials();


            }
        }
        else
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
    else
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");

    ddlProjectName.Enabled = false;
    ddlProjectName.CssClass = "form-control";

    ddlMaterials.Enabled = false;
    ddlMaterials.CssClass = "form-control";

    Panel1.Visible = false;     

}

void GetProjects()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ProjectID, ProjectName FROM Project";
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    ddlProjectName.DataSource = dr;
    ddlProjectName.DataTextField = "ProjectName";
    ddlProjectName.DataValueField = "ProjectID";
    ddlProjectName.DataBind();
    con.Close();

    ddlProjectName.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Project", ""));
}

void GetInfo(int ID)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT ProjectID FROM Project WHERE ProjectID=@ProjectID";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectID", ID);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {

            ddlProjectName.SelectedValue = dr["ProjectID"].ToString();


        }
        con.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        con.Close();
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
}

void GetMaterialsInfo(int MID) 
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT project.ProjectID, RequiredMaterials.ReqMatID FROM Project Inner join RequiredMaterials on RequiredMaterials.ProjectID = Project.ProjectID WHERE Project.ProjectID=@ProjectID AND RequiredMaterials.ReqMatID=@ReqMatID";

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectID", ID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReqMatID", MID);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {

            ddlMaterials.SelectedValue = dr["ReqMatID"].ToString();


        }
        con.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        con.Close();
        //Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
}
void GetMaterials()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT project.ProjectID, ProjectName, RequiredMaterials.ReqMatID, Products.ProductName + ' (' + SupplierName +')' as SupplierProduct FROM Project Inner join RequiredMaterials on RequiredMaterials.ProjectID = Project.ProjectID INNER JOIN SupplierProducts ON RequiredMaterials.ProductID = SupplierProducts.ProductID INNER JOIN Products ON SupplierProducts.ProductID = Products.ProductID INNER JOIN Supplier ON SupplierProducts.SupplierID = Supplier.SupplierID WHERE Project.ProjectID=@ProjectID AND RequiredMaterials.ReqMatID=@ReqMatID ";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectID", ID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReqMatID", ID);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    ddlMaterials.DataSource = dr;
    ddlMaterials.DataTextField = "SupplierProduct";
    ddlMaterials.DataValueField = "ReqMatID";
    ddlMaterials.DataBind();
    con.Close();

    ddlMaterials.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Project", ""));
}
```

}

This is how I am using my listview

```
protected void lvMaterialsList_ItemCommand(object sender,     ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Label ltRefNo = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("ltRefNo");
    Label label1 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label1");
    Label label2 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label2");
    TextBox txtAlloted = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtAlloted");
    Literal ltUsed = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("ltUsed");

    bool existingSupply = IsExisting();
    bool hasquantity = HasInventory(label1.Text);

    int alloted = Convert.ToInt32(txtAlloted.Text);
    int productid = Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text);
    string Label2 = label2.Text;

                var inventory = new DataTable();
                using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Inventory", con))
                {
                    da.Fill(inventory);
                }

                var products = new DataTable();
                using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM SupplierProducts", con))
                {
                    da.Fill(products);
                }

    if (e.CommandName == "updateused")
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;

        if (alloted < 0)
        {
            quantityCheck.Text = "cannot input negative number as quantity";
            Panel1.Visible = true;
            return;
        }

        int finalQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(inventory.Rows[0]["Quantity"]) - alloted;
        int criticalLevel = Convert.ToInt32(products.Rows[0]["CriticalLevel"]);

        bool isSafe = finalQuantity >= criticalLevel;

        string status = String.Empty;

        if (finalQuantity <= criticalLevel && finalQuantity != 0)
        {
            status = "Critical";
        }
        else if (finalQuantity > criticalLevel)
        {
            status = "Available";
        }
        else
        {
            status = "Unavailable";
        }

        if (existingSupply && hasquantity && isSafe)
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE RequiredMaterials SET Used=Used + @Used, DateModified=@DateModified WHERE ReqMatID=@ReqMatID";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Used", alloted);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReqMatID", ltRefNo.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateModified", DateTime.Now);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Inventory SET Quantity = Quantity - @Quantity, Status=@Status " +
                "WHERE ProductID=@ProductID";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", alloted);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", productid);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", status);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Withdraw VALUES (@ProjectID, @ProductID, @SupplierID, @Quantity,@UserID, @DateWithdrawn)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectID", ddlProjects.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", productid);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupplierID", DBNull.Value );
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", alloted);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", Session["userid"].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateWithdrawn", DateTime.Now);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            GetMaterialsList();

        }

        else if (!isSafe)
        {
            quantityCheck.Text = Label2 + @" Inventory count will be lower than the critical level.";
            Panel1.Visible = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            Panel1.Visible = true;
            quantityCheck.Text = Label2 + " Cannot input inventory";            
        }      
    }      
}
```

I keep on getting an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have debug the system and it show: 
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '__Page' to data type int.

Comment: Please debug and check where line when you getting error.

Comment: @KaushikMaheta. I have debug the system and edited the question

Comment: @gamered123, Which line when you getting error? Because this error is type conversation error.

Comment: why are you not using like CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ProjectID")+","+ Eval("ReqMatID")%>'

Comment: @KaushikMaheta. It does not say specifically, but it is inGetMaterials(). Databind

Comment: @Manraj would it differ than PostbackURL

Comment: @gamered123 - Your link button is inside a gridview?

Comment: first tell @gamered123 whether linkbutton is in gridview

Comment: @gamered123 - Can you show how `ProjectID` & `ReqMatID` are defined in your code behind?

Comment: @RahulSingh The project ID is working properly, but the ReqMatID Code is at the question, isn't it? Sorry I'm quite new with programming

Comment: @gamered123 - That's fine but I am only asking you to show how both are defined.

Comment: try like this <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnUpdate" runat="server" PostBackUrl='<%# "AdditionalAlloc.aspx?ProjectID=" + Eval("ProjectID")+"&ReqMatID="+ Eval("ReqMatID") %>' Text='<%# Eval("Projectname") %>' ForeColor="#0066cc"></asp:LinkButton>

Comment: ID an MID you can use for query

Comment: @RahulSingh I have edited the question. I posted all the codes behind

Comment: @Manraj I tried it, t did not get any ID

Comment: then your code dont get ID in querystring .Debug it and check whether querystring contains ID or not

Answer (score 0):

Since you have your `LinkButton` on the form itself and not inside any databound control your current code will not work because `Eval` method can be only used with databound controls. Now, I am really not sure how you are able to get `ProjectID` working. You should always try to avoid complicating the mark-up code. If you have everything in your code behind file why complicate things? Simply do it in your code behind file.

MarkUp (aspx page):-

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnUpdate" Text="Additional" class="btn btn-primary"
     runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
```

In Code Behind:-

```
lbtnUpdate.PostBackUrl = String.Format("AdditionalAlloc.aspx?ID={0}&MID={1}",
                                                           ProjectID,ReqMatID);
```

Comment: I just put it in a databound control, but the code that I use still gives the same errors

Comment: @gamered123 - Which databound control? `Gridview`, `Repeater` which one?

Comment: I put it in a listview

Comment: @gamered123 - So you mean to say you have multiple LinkButtons now? how you are binding the listview?

Comment: I do, still how I did in the my question

Comment: I still get the project, but the materials still are nothing

Comment: @gamered123 - How come buddy? You are saying you have added a `listview` and you are not even binding it. How come it can work. I wanna help you out but without proper inputs it's impossible.

Comment: Thanks Bro, Really appreciated. I have edited the question and include the listview where I put it.

Comment: @gamered123 - You can remove rest of the code. Simply show how your binding your `lvMaterialsList`? Or how toy are calling `lvMaterialsList.DataBind()`?

Comment: I have added on how I was using the listview. I didn't think that the problems would be there

Comment: @gamered123 - Buddy for you I have created a test project and it's working just fine for me (with your exact LinkButton code). Definitely you are not passing `ReqMatID` & `ProjectID` correctly. At `lvMaterialsList.DataSource` please check what you are sending.

Comment: Thanks bro. What do you mean code behind in your answer. Is it the CS

Comment: @gamered123 - Yes the .aspx.cs file is known as code behind file.

Comment: I tried using your code behinde. But ProjectID and ReqMatID don't exist

Comment: @gamered123 - I have posted the answer if you don't have a ListView. And you should have MID, ID (which you are using in your code).